# IICS: How to deal with API which returns first character as a number but not letter?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics, informatica-data-integration-hub, iics-di

Hi informatica developers,

I am working on a XML-based REST API. I want to get the data from the API and save it to a flat file.

However, one problem is that this API is returning the object whose first character starts with number but not letters. Below is an example response from the API:

```
<sg_response>
<sgscore>
    <scores>
        <score>
            <period>2022-07</period>
            <score>650</score>
            <min>405</min>
            <25th>585</25th>
            <50th>660</50th>
            <75th>710</75th>
            <max>830</max>
        </score>
```

So when I create the mapping, I got this error:
[image]

Hence, I modified the output fields, I added a 'p' in front of the column name:
[image]

Which mapped back to the API response like this:
[image]

However this cannot solve the problem, when I run the mapping I got this error:

**[FATAL] Service Info not found for the service 'WebServices_h2r_udt_1i5fk_ONLY_H2R_XMAP_H2R - 4 m.contains.i0.contains.i3 Map: './25th' is not a valid XPath. (Invalid literal found: 25th [err:XPST0003]).- for more information see file://D:/SecureAgent/apps/Data_Integration_Server/data/CMReports/Tmp/2023-07-04/CmInternal_ServiceValidator_A7d55926e-5699-4473-aee4-7829973da881/Events.cme <log_file>D:/SecureAgent/apps/Data_Integration_Server/data/CMReports/Tmp/2023**

Based on the error I guess the problem should be caused by the 25th, 50th, 75th issue, because in the error it says **"'./25th' is not a valid XPath. (Invalid literal found: 25th [err:XPST0003]"**

Do you have any ideas as how to solve the problem? Have you encountered with an API who returns the first character as a number but not a letter? Do you know how to modify the XPath? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

to whom who has similar questions, I have contacted Informatica support, and they says that this function is just disallowed. They have created a change request to add this function in the future.

For now, if really need to do this task, one has to use Java transformation and intelligent parser to achieve this.